# Getting the latest 10 records in semi-complex MySQL JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    orderSummaries.sessionDate,
    orderSummaries.sessionTime,
    orderSummaries.sessionID,
    orderSummaries.loggedInUser,
    orderSummaries.orderTotal,
    salesTracking.orderID,
    salesTracking.itemID,
    schedule5.gameName,
    schedule5.serialNumber,
    schedule5.uniqueID

FROM orderSummaries

JOIN salesTracking ON orderSummaries.sessionID = salesTracking.orderID
JOIN schedule5 ON salesTracking.itemID = schedule5.uniqueID

WHERE orderSummaries.username = 'someemail@gmail.com'

ORDER BY orderSummaries.sessionDate DESC

LIMIT 10;
```

The query works okay if I don't have the "ORDER BY" statement in there - but without it, it is pulling records from who knows where in the tables. The tables are all very big, with several thousands records. I am ultimately just aiming to grab the last ten, for any given email address.

Is there an easier way to grab the most recent 10 (or so) records, without using the ORDER BY statement?

Comment: Define "most recent".  `ORDER BY` is how you define the order of the results before taking a subset of those results.  Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @David It's not that I don't WANT to use it. It just doesn't work when I do. It breaks the query. So I am wondering if there's another way.

Comment: @JohnHubler: How does it "break" the query?  In the question you state: *"The query works okay if I don't have the "ORDER BY" statement in there - but without it, it is pulling records from who knows where in the tables."* - Which basically states that the query works without `ORDER BY`, but doesn't work without `ORDER BY`.  Which is it?  What's the specific problem?  I suspect that addressing the "break" that you're observing will be more fruitful than trying to find a way to order data without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @David Sorry for the confusion. Okay, so if it DON'T include the ORDER BY, I get results returned, but the results are not the most recent database entries. If I DO include the ORDER BY, the query just perpetually runs, and never returns any results.

Comment: @JohnHubler: Sounds like the next step would be to profile the query (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) to observe its execution plan.  If the query is performing very slowly then you'll want to identify the specific bottleneck, which you may be able to address with an index or other change to the schema.